# Grails mapping multiple actions to a single HTTP method (verb)

Tags: rest, grails, action, url-mapping, http-method

I want to map multiple actions to a single HTTP verb like this

```
"/product"(controller: "product"){
action : [POST: ["save", "clone"] ]

}
```

Is there any way in grails 2.2.4 to achieve this ?

Comment: How do you ever expect that to work? Posting to /product calls BOTH actions? That makes NO sense. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: do you want to _restrict_ the actions to certain http methods?  that would be done in the controller using `static allowedMethods`

Comment: why don't you map one action and call multiple methods  /controllers from it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is trivial to do - but not directly in *UrlMappings*. Implementing your example would make the request/response lifecycle confusing, where and how is the response built?

Here are two possible approaches to accomplish the same thing, depending on your circumstances:

1. Have a primary controller method (action) that handles request and response and just calls the other action(s) as a side effect. This is the way I usually see something like this implemented, mainly because it is obvious where the request and response is handled.
2. Have a delegating controller method (action) that does nothing but call the other actions. The other actions are together responsible for handling request and response. This is more similar to what you're trying to do in your example.